# Getting a view by id from a running eclipse instance

Tags: view, eclipse-plugin

I have created the following StatisticsView Class for a custom view for my Eclipse plugin:

```java
public  class StatisticsView extends ViewPart {
    public StyledText projectname;
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
            GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(3, false);
        parent.setLayout(layout);
        //Project Name
        Label projectnameLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
        projectnameLabel.setText("Project name: ");
        projectname = new StyledText(parent, SWT.NONE);
        projectname.setText("Anything for now");
                               .
                               .
    }
                               .
                               .
    public String getProjectName() {
        return projectname.getText();
    }

    public void updateData(Stats statistics) {
              projectname.setText(statistics.getProjectName());     //causes the error
                             .
                             .
    }
}
```

The plugin.xml file has the following viewPoint:

```xml
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.views">
      <category
            name="XYZ"
            id="XYZ">
      </category>
      <view
            name="Statistics"
            inject="true"
            category="XYZ"
            class="XYZ.view.StatisticsView"
            id="XYZ.view.StatisticsView">
      </view>
   </extension>
```

I run the project by using the **"Run as Eclipse Application"** which opens a new Eclipse Instance(just gonna call it, **Inner Eclipse**) and where my View is shown.

I have in my Project(from where I run the project i.e not the Inner Eclipse) another class **ResultsListener** in which I try to find this view using its "id" like this:

```java
                .....
IWorkbenchWindow workbenchWindow = null;
IWorkbenchWindow[] allWindows = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getWorkbenchWindows();
for (IWorkbenchWindow window : allWindows) {
      workbenchWindow = window;
      if (workbenchWindow != null) {
             System.out.println("Found workbench");
             break;
      }
}
IWorkbenchPage activePage = workbenchWindow.getActivePage();
IViewPart viewPart = activePage.findView("XYZ.view.StatisticsView");
if(viewPart==null) {
      System.out.println("View Not found");
}
StatisticsView myView = (StatisticsView)viewPart;
System.out.println(myView.getProjectName());      //causes the error
myView.updateData(stat);
```

Whenever I'm calling any method of the found view it gives me the following error:
`org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access`

Within my ResultsListener class I need to do some analysis and then update the widgets of the view that then need to be reflected in the Inner Eclipse.
Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: 'Invalid thread access' means you are running UI code in a non-UI thread. How is this 'ResultListener' being run?

Comment: The ResultListener is a simple class that makes some calculations and is being simply called by other classes. It doesn't have any UI components. How can I make it run as a UI thread?

Comment: But how is that code being run? What calls it? The SWT Display class has asyncExec and syncExec methods to run code in the UI thread, but from the look of it all this code should be in the UI thread.

Comment: Its being called by a "Analysis Kickoff" Class that creates a thread to use its run method to populate data into the ResultsListener. I need that same data to fill the widgets of my view. So after getting the view by Id should I create a new UI thread and call the methods using that?

Comment: In SWT there is only a single UI thread, you cannot create a new UI thread. Instead, put your UI code (where you get the "Invalid thread access") in a `Runnable` and execute it via `Display#asyncE‌xec(...)` or `Display#syncE‌xec(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Invalid thread access' means you are running UI code in a non-UI thread.

There is only ever one UI thread, you can arrange to run code in the UI thread using:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

where `runnable` is something implementing `Runnable`. Tthis could just be a lambda:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(() -> { ... code block ... });
```

`asyncExec` runs the code asynchronously. You can also use `syncExec` to run the code synchronously (the current thread will block until the UI code has run).

Code running in the UI thread should not do any long running operations as this will block the UI.

Note: Ideally you should have a separate non-UI 'model' class containing your data. The view can get and set values in the model and the analysis code can then also access the results in the model without having to do any UI code.

Comment: Within the runnable i am just setting the content for the widgets of the View. It isnt doing any non-UI work. But the syncExec() or asyncExec() methods start like after 20 seconds. Which kind of means the UI thread is working on something else before it serves my request. Is there a way to make it run immediately?

Comment: No, these run as soon as the UI thread is free to handle them, but that normally is measured in milliseconds not seconds. It sounds like the UI thread may be doing some long running work that shouldn't be in that thread.